# MySQL query result is giving wrong values

Tags: php, mysql

guys! I'm in trouble with my MySQL database. When I try to access the fields it doesn't return the exact value. Here is the code.

```html
<?php
  $host = "localhost";
 $user = "******";
 $pass = "******";
 $db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.");
 mysql_select_db("*****") or die("Unable to select database!");
  $form_username=$_POST["username"];
 $form_password=$_POST["password"];
 $query="
  SELECT username, password FROM users
 ";
 $result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die("Unable to send the query".mysql_error());
 $index=0;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
  $username[$index]=row[0];
  $password[$index]=row[1];
  $index++;
 }
 
 for($i=0; $i<=$index; $i++)
 {
  if($form_username==$username[$i]&& $form_password==$password[$i])
  {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["login"]="OK";
   header("Location: ************");
   die();
  }
 }
```

The **if** statement inside the **for** operator returns false for every given value. When I **echo** every username and password like this:

```html
echo $form_username." ".$username[0]." ".$form_password." ".$password[0]."<br>";
 echo $form_username." ".$username[1]." ".$form_password." ".$password[1]."<br>";
 echo $form_username." ".$username[2]." ".$form_password." ".$password[2]."<br>";
```

It **echo** me this:

admin r 12345 o

admin r 12345 o

admin r 12345 o

I really don't know where the problem is.
I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use PDO or MySQLi. You are storing passwords in plaintext, they need to be securely hashed. And I'm sure that if given the chance you would also be vulnerable to SQL injection, so look that up too.

Comment: You should be getting an `undefined row constant` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should this bit:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $username[$index]=row[0];
    $password[$index]=row[1];
    $index++;
}
```

Read:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $username[$index] = $row[0];
    $password[$index] = $row[1];
    $index++;
}
```

Note missing $ on the variable names.

Comment: This is the correct answer, in the first instance, PHP is treating 'row' as a string, so doing row[0] is returning the first character 'r'. Hence OP's output of `admin r 12345 o`. Interesting to say the least.

Comment: Heh nicely deciphered @Enstage. I didn't realise that's why it had that output, I just quickly did a scan for obvious issues. As someone who uses lots of different languages, I regularly make mistakes like this so it's the first thing I look for. I tend to use code formatting with a lot more whitespace to make things easier to read.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I didn't get any errors or warnings before but now, when corrected, it worked. I get really angry when realizing what stupid mistakes I do.

Comment: Hey @zumbata we all make such mistakes. PHP has a habit of doing things that don't work but also don't cause errors. Could you do me a favour and click the answer accepted button on this one?